# Howto to limit post per categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to limit 2 post per categories (categories id is 12,13,16 and 18) on my homepage and here is my `index.php` content :

```
$layout_type_for_index = osetin_get_settings_field('layout_type_for_index');

if(get_query_var('page')){
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
}else{
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
}
if($paged == 1){
$sticky_posts = osetin_get_field('sticky_posts', false, false, true);
}
$os_posts_per_page = osetin_get_number_of_posts_per_page();
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'position',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => $os_posts_per_page,
'paged' => $paged,
'tax_query' => array()
);
```

But I don't know how to do it, any help please?

Comment: And what should `build_index_posts()` be exactly? A custom function that we know nothing about. Post that as well...

Comment: Hi thanks, I just added, I copy paste the code somehow only half before and now I pasted the whole one

Comment: Still no `build_index_posts()` function anywhere...

Comment: ok,I have look again

Comment: Is it help yet? I found that function but dunno If I got it right

Comment: No, in sublime or notepad++ try searching the files for `build_index_posts` and when you see something like `function build_index_posts($layout, $placement, $query){...}` post that here. Because that function controls the query.

Comment: I think this one right? thanks for helping me

Comment: I added 'showposts' => '2', 'cat' => '12,13,16,18', its work but only show 2 post from cat 12?? what about cat 13,16 and 18?

Comment: `cat` needs to be array if you want to show specific categories. You want to show 2 from each category, this is something entirely different, and you'll need to modify the query.

Comment: You should probably just do one query for each category.